# cannot debug python GAE Django

Tags: python, django

I have a simple test app that seem to run fine.  I'm trying to debug by placing the following in the code:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

When I run the app I get the following fatal error that I don't understand:

```
ERROR:root:Exception in request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\App Engine\testapp\djang
o\core\handlers\base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\AppEngine\rtest\polls\vi
ews.py", line 13, in create
    cd = form.cleaned_data
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\AppEngine\rtest\polls\vi
ews.py", line 13, in create
    cd = form.cleaned_data
  File "C:\Python25\lib\bdb.py", line 48, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\bdb.py", line 67, in dispatch_line
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
BdbQuit
INFO:root:"POST /create HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:root:"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Why am I getting errors when I try to debug?

Comment: How are you running the application? Are you using Django's development server (``./manage.py runserver``) or a 'real' webserver?

Comment: To anyone facing this error message working with Docker, see this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854967/docker-compose-and-pdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the GAE runtime doesn't support pdb. Hard Luck.

If you want a similar runtime, you should check out [Apphosted](https://apphosted.com/)

Comment: After seeing the above answer I found this article with a solution: http://jjinux.blogspot.com/2008/05/python-debugging-google-app-engine-apps.html